# css/Less calc() method is crashing my IE10

Tags: css, less, internet-explorer-10

I am trying to get a height in a div to be exactly 55px less then the parent div.

I tried to do this: `height: calc(~"100% - 55px");` in less which creates this: `height: calc(100% - 55px);`

This works fine in Chrome and Firefox, but crashes on IE10.

It's not that it does not work but it crashes it. This is very strange i tried to find some info on line but can't see anything.

Also, this happens only with the height. If i were to use the `calc()` method on the width it runs fine.

Any idea on how i can get to the bottom of this?

Comment: That sounds weird. Can you provide a jsFiddle example that demonstrates it in action?

Comment: My very basic test fiddle with your code (http://jsfiddle.net/wyRXp/) doesn't crash the browser, so clearly there's something more complex going on than what you've said. Please show us an example which trigger the error.

Comment: Ok, so following your example i have created a jsFiddle demo for this. I have put in more of my other code in to see where it breaks and it looks like it might be the combination of kendoUI and the calc() method. I will try to trace it to the exact bit of kendoUI that is clashing with the method and bring it up with the guys at Telerik, they will hopefully be able to shed some light on this.
http://fiddle.jshell.net/zawisza/75mtH/

Comment: Sorry KendoUI guys, i have blamed you prematurely in my comment above.
I found the real reason. See my answer below.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I found the problem. There was a height:inherit inside one of the inside divs. 
Clearly IE gets super confused on this as the value is calculated and apparently not inheritable. All well now.

So in other words you **can't** do something like this:

```
<div style="height:100%">
  <div style="height: calc(100% - 50px)">
    <div style="height:inherit">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

if you do IE10 will crash, here is an example : http://jsfiddle.net/wyRXp/1/

here i took out the inherit height: http://jsfiddle.net/wyRXp/2/
and it works fine.

Both above samples work fine in Firefox and Chrome

Comment: Well done for isolating the problem. :)  You should mark your answer as accepted to help others looking for the same problem. BTW, for what it's worth, your fiddle crashes IE10 but not IE11.

Answer (score 1):

There's a known issue with `calc()` in IE10

> Internet Explorer (in accordance with the spec) does not accept calculations without spaces for additions/subtractions (ie. calc(100%-30px) is invalid, but calc(100% - 30px) works fine).

Refer to [CanIUse.com](http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc).

Most probable reason of your crash is that the **Less** is removing spaces when escaping the value.

Comment: Even with the spaces taken out, the worst that should happen is that it would just ignore it; it shouldn't crash the browser (and as far as my testing goes, it doesn't).

Comment: You never know. Maybe, without spaces, this particular value is interpreted somehow by IE10 but it's interpreted wrong. Since `calc()` is executed on almost every event it might cause huge CPU usage finally leading to crash.

Comment: I considered that and tried adding additional css code via a separate css file that was not generated from less. But it did not help.